# How prevalent is "I'm game" compared to "I'm in"?

Tags: synonyms, slang

Is it common to say "I'm game" in place of "I'm in" or "Count me in"?

Is it used often in American English?

Comment: Don't know about American English but very common in British English to mean _yes, I'll join in_ or _yes, I'll do that_. _I'm up for that_ is also commonplace.

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39078/does-the-phrase-whos-in-or-im-in-exist-in-informal-english. Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6426/what-does-im-game-mean-and-whats-its-correct-usage

Comment: A lot of people use the phrase `I'm game` here in South Africa.

Comment: What about "I'm down" then?

Answer (score 9):

No, **not** in place of those other two. *I'm game* expresses willingness, but not yet commitment. *I'm in* and *Count me in* are synonymous, expressing commitment.

Answer (score 1):

- I have used other answers from this post to improve mine

They have slightly different meanings. As far as usage, there is this:

"I am in" - I will participate / I am participating.

"I am game" - I will participate (the subject is very confident about it but not yet in)

"Count me in" - you can rely on the subject's participation (suportive)

(I had to get them separately because ngram wouldn't show them together)

[image: A Google ngram image showing "I'm happy" in much greater usage than I'm in love, followed by relatively lower usage of "I'm in trouble", and almost none of "I'm in the house".]

[image: A Google ngram image of "count me in" with significantly lower results, percentage wise than the previous graph]

[image: A Google ngram image of "I'm game" that indicate an order of magnitude greater than "count me in", but significantly lower than any of the first graph]

[image: A Google ngram of "I'm in " but in this case including question marks in the query and a space after the word "in". The resulting graph is several orders of magnitude smaller than other graphs on the page]

I hope it helps.

Comment: "I'm in" is used other ways more commonly. "I'm in the bathroom", " I'm in Tokyo", etc. I don't think they can be directly compared this way.

Comment: I agree with @GobTies in that the N-grams are skewed by other meanings. However, I definitely think it's a phrase that has changed drastically over time. I find it more natural to say "I'm down". Some older friends say "I'm in" and "Count me in". Only my parents say "I'm game".

Answer (score 0):

No it is not, all three has 3 different meanings.

1. I am game or I am the game - This phrase has been often used on TV by famous WWE superstar **Triple H**. When using this phrase he mean, that he can change the game, he has total control over the game, he has confidence, no matter who is the opponent he will win. Also that, wrestle there in the ring with any wrestler is not actually the game, but when you compete with Triple H is when the actual game of wrestling begins, because he is the most experienced one and you'll experience the real of game only when you play the veteran player.
   Similarly in car racing **Michael Schumacher** can say so.

   In other context "I am game" also means that you want to participate in some task or you're agreeing to an offer, some meeting, some outing/party etc. This kinda started when people used to play cards, and its your turn to put the money on game. So by saying, "I am still gaming" you put the money on table, and sends the confirmation that you're still in game and you're not out of money, Which in daily speaking English became, "I am game" means you want to participate
2. I am in - Simply means, you also wants to play or you have voluntarily wants to participate or in some context you are agreeing with the fact or giving votes.
3. Count me in - Pretty much similar to #2, but here head count matters, lets take an example. To book a party hall you the total head count should be 40 people, when you share this thing with people some one says "Count me in" means, that guy full fills the head count. In another context, when someone voluntarily wants to help a group of people in some social task, then "count me in" you are just added yourself to the group.

Comment: "I am the game" is unrelated to simply "I'm game." ("I'm game" means "I will take part, yes, aggreed, let's do it".)  There are any number of phrases that happen to have "game" in them.